# Can't get text next to toggle to line up properly

Tags: php, css, navigation, wordpress-theming

I added the text "MENY" next to the toggle (nav trigger) since I thought it would be confusing for desktop visitors when visiting my site. However I can't seem to get the text to line up nicely with the toggle icon. How do I lower or raise the text next to the icon so it looks good?

Here's the .php:

```
<a href="#" id="nav-trigger">
<span style="font-family: Source Sans Pro; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1; margin-left: 5px; font-weight: 700;">MENY</span> m
```

Image of issue can be found here: [a link]http://i41.tinypic.com/2jd3l9k.png (not enough rep to add images)

Also, if there's a way to bring them closer together... but that's just a bonus!

Thanks for all help! I'm a beginner trying to learn. :)

**Entire header.php** >nav-trigger<

```
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <?php thb_body_start(); ?>

    <div id="page">

        <?php thb_header_before(); ?>

        <header id="header">
            <?php thb_header_start(); ?>

            <div class="header-container">

                <div class="wrapper">
                    <?php
                        $logo = thb_get_option('main_logo');
                        $logo_2x = thb_get_option('main_logo_retina');

                        if( !empty($logo['id']) && !empty($logo_2x['id']) ) : ?>
                        <?php $logo_metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata($logo['id']); ?>
                        <style>
                            @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
                                #logo {
                                    background-image: url('<?php echo thb_image_get_size($logo_2x['id'], 'full'); ?>');
                                    background-size: <?php echo $logo_metadata['width']; ?>px, <?php echo $logo_metadata['height']; ?>px;
                                }

                                #logo img { visibility: hidden; }
                            }
                        </style>

                        <?php endif;
                    ?>
                    <h1 id="logo">
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
                            <?php if( isset($logo['id']) && $logo['id'] != '' ) : ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo thb_image_get_size($logo['id'], 'full'); ?>" alt="">
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </a>
                    </h1>

                    <?php thb_nav_before(); ?>

                    <a href="#" id="nav-trigger">
<span style="font-family: Source Sans Pro; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1; margin-left: 5px; font-weight: 700;">MENY</span> m
```

```
                    <div class="nav-wrapper">
                        <nav id="main-nav" class="main-navigation primary">
                            <?php thb_nav_start(); ?>

                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

                            <?php thb_nav_end(); ?>
                        </nav>

                        <nav id="mobile-nav" class="main-navigation primary">
                            <?php thb_nav_start(); ?>

                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

                            <?php thb_nav_end(); ?>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <?php thb_nav_after(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapper">
```

Comment: Solved it. Just had to add some line-hight and vertical-align. Safari was the culprit. So still looks a bit weird there but all other major browsers looks fins so can't be bothered with it... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Create a div with the image in it.
Create a div with the text in it.

```
<div class='myimage'><img src='yourimg'></div>
<div class='menytext'>meny</div>

.menytext{float:left;margin:0 0 0 -50px} (for example)
```

Float the text div over the image and then you will be able to position the text however you like.

Comment: Thanks! But the toggle icon is a font character, not an inline- or background image.

Comment: Same principle.  Float it in a div, style it to suit.

Comment: Thanks again. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I keep messing it up! Added the full header.php if you'd like to show me or guide me as to where the class is supposed to go. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

because inline tag has a space, you can add  between them, like

```
<a href="#" id="nav-trigger"><!--
--><span style="font-family: Source Sans Pro; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1; margin-left: 5px;   font-weight: 700;">MENY</span>
```